# How to find out the default system copy register?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, linux, ssh

I want to know how to find the default copy register on any machine. I `ssh` into different machines and use vi. But on some of them the `"+` and/or `"*` registers don't work. Also when I can use my mouse I can mark text and copy it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> while that doesn't work in my own vi.

`vi scp` isn't ideal because I want to look around the machines and occasionally copy some details. I don't want to have to first `ssh` into the machine find out the file's location and to then use `scp`.

Also would it be possible to copy the remote machine's copy register onto my local machine's copy register?

Comment: I haven't seen a plugin for such task, but this would be good idea, for now you can try to use tmux buffers to copy between remote sessions.

Comment: Use `ssh -XY` to enable X11 forwarding; the Vim on the machine you're ssh-ing to will still need +clipboard though. See the duplicate question, which also contains links to questions which provide work-arounds if +clipboard isn't available.